# Clustering methods recommendation

Tags: r, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, non-linear-regression

I tried to a use K-means clustering method to create a plot based on the dataset below. The point I was trying to prove is that there's a non-linear relationship between `Uploads` and `Subscribes`.

If you look at the x-axis of the plot below, the more uploads, it didn't increase subscribes too much among these different color groups, which I think will help to prove the non-linear relationship.

Then my professor told me the current clustering method might not work for this data, I might need to try another clustering method.

To be honest, I'm confused and hope to get your valued opinions.

Codes:

```
# Remove the most absurd outliers and check boxplot 
FGPdat_main <- FGPdat_main[-which(FGPdat_main$Views>42000000000),]

# Formatting Views in billions
FGPdat_main$Views <- FGPdat_main$Views/1000000000

k <- 5         
kmeans_5 <- kmeans(FGPdat_main[,c("Uploads","Subscribes")], k)
plot(FGPdat_main[,c("Uploads","Subscribes")], 
     col = kmeans_5$cluster, 
     main = "Uploads by subscribes clustering distribution",
     xlab = "Uploads",
     ylab = "Subscribes in millions")
points(kmeans_5$centers, col = 1:k, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

Plot:

[image]

```
Subscribe Uploads Views
      130  14436 101000000000
      103   4075 24721409353
       74    504 52205077882
       66  36108 48971762733
       65   3839 17102586827
       56   1335 28732684479
       55  46186 39737186824
       52    168   910786944
       51   4619 23932906957
       49    226 10030830255
       49    378 26925658854
       47    670 20764862998
       44    161 19295603246
       43    410  8230300645
       43   5157 15626066631
       41    134   837179518
       41  99591 40175523093
       40    137  4185257983
       40    171   977596875
       39    375  3281315514
       38   1679 10606913311
       37    178   322656423
       37    823  8400833587
       37  11499 19051471207
       36   2183  9039779673
       36    103   365647415
       35    535  7822234254
       35    207 16121095046
       34  35017 32739618144
       34     79    64475965
       34   3136  6393482689
       33    256  8421427330
       33    361  8252486361
       33    128 19734443616
       33    214  7698720724
       33   6716 15704618949
       33    608  6449845945
       32    346 20769704700
       32  17692 21557614651
       32   1017  4295524182
       31   2573 12663825098
       31    692  4738908033
       31    157   361266155
       31    816 27468103368
       30   3074 22607347709
       30    157   307093494
       30   1498 12386979621
       30    308  2048032203
       30    773  4219472240
       29   5770 11864486207
       29    883  9587079657
       29    712 23024557040
       28   7847 14483678290
       28   3758 15150012854
       28    352 10189524761
       28   1850 10340540740
       28   3049 13228834980
       28   3034 13903430093
       28  23126 23876381653
       28    245   226711071
       28  41815 23713980813
       27     87 13263612813
       27 100025  8037523805
       27     27   592561264
       27  20598 11204339470
       27     74    18903214
       27    115 18305497244
       27     67 11580328151
       27   9379 15959314601
       26   8646  9763057043
       26    282  9402376998
       26   2747 11474861629
       26    106 14913628204
       26   1144  3580312271
       26     85 14346572866
       26    139 18791930557
       26   2759 14808811438
       25 140325 33948643100
       25    189  6880036800
       25   1105  9300268516
       25   4605 12545186500
       25    725  7371555928
       25     89   299770638
       25   1128 22764516187
       25   1132 12199923012
       25    174   500456311
       25    447 10354132018
       24    630  2474832757
       24    103  4695107571
       24   1654 36758961894
       24   5832 13365915478
       24     46   121102692
       24    223  9074952590
       23   4456 12260817474
       23 151229  4219244372
       23  36570 17093038181
       23   1685  5493818690
       23    338 13690735654
       23      8   320642955
       23   4741 14990018313
       23   1044  2084965515
       23   2870  3521137903
       23    171  9198160858
       23   1290  8231190181
       23   3924  7217624548
       22   3312 16182437102
       22  10102 12925824815
       22  17766 13106073597
       22    520  4710097127
       22    112  1521375681
       22     36  6389507792
       22   3934 12083303169
       22   3546 15701845643
       22  69013 16094643099
       21    406  4194607781
       21     51    20319076
       21   7152 11188026855
       21    528 12267530146
       21  83244 16559649980
       21   4644 10836878865
       21  10475 11643456827
       21    403  2724104308
       21   1210  5185826962
       21    733  2059549388
       21     13   177644226
       21    494 18403531981
       21    238  4449091304
       21     51 14285971695
       21    674  4948968131
       21    486  9539913898
       20     22   103328638
       20    321  9990301957
       20    247 12742112174
       20    205   815202893
       20    223   851651234
       20    487  3503681332
       20   2415  8906761537
       20   4205  7287261609
       20     50   390244841
       20   2208  8731634538
       20   6647 16502284357
       20    853  6426538705
       20   1869  4783985544
       20    251 10241291653
       19    226  1449686602
       19    172  5342557378
       19   1543   560578248
       19    837  2519939497
       19    561  4827632185
       19 139460  4800771004
       19    164 17334015616
       19   5700 10018951421
       19    360   828135847
       19   1312  4298175322
       19    314  5232587326
       19    392 13321498446
       19  17001 15711212480
       19   1791  6168678404
       19    161  6067039576
       19     70  1449768492
       19     18    34555836
       19   2244  5159310023
       18    111 13591003030
       18    189  1474973553
       18   3858  7617316333
       18    504  3442421058
       18   1142 11338082307
       18    779  5226219834
       18     68 11769405995
       18   2077  3307087406
       18    218  4369390508
       18    237  5944599965
       18    168  2391546342
       18    165    97098734
       18   7578 17333436469
       18   3833  3946700561
       18    367  2172255350
       17     69   899952993
       17   2600 14540013198
       17    148    53857449
       17     70   146290815
       17     34  1511270109
       17   4569 13654283354
       17   1172  5952106750
       17    254  1903631347
       17     42  3393927800
       17     65   238760013
       17   5736  5958810528
       17 154714  5885347331
       17    481  6713407246
       17    805  8630995133
       17   1051  2703790497
       17   2134  2675298184
       17    456  6395052599
       17   3374  4888988211
       17    727  8285922880
       16  12045 34046571715
       16    157  2279449621
       16   1993  3434717763
       16   1374  5631471296
       16    775  7395527310
       16    524  1483310241
       16   3970  7650336758
       16   4584  9417350407
       16     86  6255424033
       16    263  9939041005
       16   2408  6176051259
       16   3265  1733819133
       16   1732  3450439721
       16    135  1693819617
       16      1      392475
       16    624  6832856693
       16    363  7781715835
       16    309  2944325452
       16    189   404814874
       16     29  1883125832
       16    143  3583255451
       16   2568  5774755441
       16    948  4704912542
       16    397  6128920114
       16     31  8678580123
       16     56    36111825
       16    570  3054141036
       16    240  5140450926
       16     83  1108997135
       16    115  4744620141
       16    492  7937130417
       16    914  8697261611
       15    316  3482900621
       15    367  1787630461
       15    169  1423931707
       15   2849  1633878963
       15   1655  5193516783
       15    303  6447843341
       15    369  2258383150
       15    163   117719478
       15     88  9572370846
       15    121 14655454069
       15   2273  3259775124
       15    153  8122416361
       15   1091   777176817
       15   5220  3968239637
       15    371  1871794237
       15    656  4351970462
       15   2584  6152996226
       15     85   442379128
       15   1464  6709240661
       15   1645  4625857706
       15    789  3266964743
       15     41  3690078765
       15   1063  8177584130
       15   2029  9200102739
       15   2598  8487328823
       15     15   349527348
       15     80  3425291337
       15    631 13563879405
       15    248  2673825866
       15    397  3706868265
       15   1825  7790828794
       15    285  1227193602
       15  83438 14955853756
       15    111 13061079900
       15   1005  2334617224
       15   1037  1874259356
       15    619  7152409721
       14    121  4992415990
       14    265  6303854646
       14   8283 11330419216
       14   1566  3099305183
       14    435  3579916008
       14    500  6212014070
       14   2708  5348069270
       14    485  1742311244
       14    511  2402036181
       14   1340  5086638656
       14   2704  3153683186
       14   1360  7193512052
       14    551  1928756237
       14    273  4470347281
       14   3907  9809097718
       14   4716  7364923471
       14    114  2798759150
       14   8178  4900625276
       14    264   780355803
       14   2490  5262725899
       14    282  1622040618
       14    374  1608319239
       14   1905  8377991974
       14    785  8174703793
       14    885  9616870984
       14   3576  7290115200
       14   2997  1829002626
       14   6636  3167732904
       14   2945 11327961609
       14     59  4491839261
       14    159 13262449578
       14    848  2425126848
       14    380  5014589188
       14    679  2461366147
       14    169  2459411584
       13   9273  3563256302
       13   1910  3824224470
       13     90  7439562326
       13    128 12434510443
       13     78   380721780
       13  33062  6581551736
       13   1353  8002553410
       13   7408  8843893791
       13    267  1959424628
       13   3089  1684036370
       13    141 10526007772
       13  62183  2665206233
       13   4367  4015563098
       13  18623  7492573137
       13   3940  4797732444
       13   3099  2456039168
       13   3080  2734495008
       13    147  4038867511
       13    771  1270199776
       13     81  2590939069
       13    254  6189851783
       13    247   461556935
       13   1323 13712358088
       13   1548  2314876754
       13     32    70678941
       13     64  6945739257
       13     67   134773455
       13   2348  5860247004
       13   3207 12675495467
       13 136434 10071136389
       13   3366  6111249252
       13     29    11046741
       13    247    78472588
       13    320  7013787123
       13  18522  8019793124
       13    202  4273838888
       13    404  2887209015
       13   3666  2642450909
       13    153  3506310977
       13    840  2238000412
       13   2706  3519168204
       13    167  7195236861
       13   1143 10122225969
       13    162  1012777048
       13     63   490178684
       13    258  1333065928
       13    524  3166919033
       13  47045  5316354547
       13    327  1112854083
       13   1042  1308627526
       13    569  3269537177
       13   4951  2715916211
       13    262  1066044510
       13    812  2124838117
       13    352  1680999827
       13   2588  3277056020
       13   1157  4368873772
       13   1008  3205738507
       13   1894  4564703842
       13    130   258460740
       13    455  5265822055
       13     14   108025141
       12    134 11646109919
       12   3323  3715045944
       12    478  2260164417
       12   1224  3276454273
       12    233  9323124108
       12    350  4662968796
       12    328   772718126
       12    876  3667920968
       12    289  2425671486
       12    130  2841607695
       12   1051  2077761444
       12   2904  2662384551
       12    219   649047997
       12   1095  2817224314
       12    102  4227652735
       12   1541  4731828994
       12   2055  3218045324
       12   1502  4142301090
       12     12  2709040570
       12     32  6200297020
       12    471  2634754712
       12   3488  3686703395
       12   3785 11180868997
       12    337  5114166936
       12    259  6029026543
       12   2521  5363902321
       12   1839  6011153172
       12     58  1061040721
       12     39  3644813628
       12    361  2260496396
       12    283  1883939269
       12   4210  4915781205
       12   1162  3138414360
       12    366  4666994807
       12    773  5688388542
       12   5947  3771609542
       12  40743  8304300560
       12   1061  3752836212
       12   1028  2774202513
       12    413  1717381686
       12  16578  7990311742
       12    177  2362256011
       12    743  2975539689
       12  16753  6302599978
       12  23948  6607753457
       12    186  9567812814
       12    571  2612876847
       12  12917  3062326455
       12    304  3205284711
       12    167  4711128881
       12    375  3457444671
       12   3998  3787391961
       12    400   781701094
       12    744  2263823554
       12   1430  1381702247
       12    362  4004445565
       12   2786  2374857426
       12   2880 14880158880
       12    334  2100516783
       12   3273  4102497489
       12   3275  9682168074
       12   3641  3749315749
       12    810  5945406295
       12    338  1918379606
       12    140  2748842405
       12    620  1187938408
       12    915  1028320980
       12    657  2355359978
       12   1060  9585822437
       12    987  4320977849
       12    459  5542122178
       12    377  1115617921
       11    412  2398442538
       11    188   534961040
       11    299  5276362941
       11   2051  3860025116
       11    315  5318278283
       11    368     6589417
       11   1496  2750523069
       11    135   792917770
       11   9436  3854599589
       11    126  1743078517
       11   1311  4318920328
       11    718  2824535740
       11    135  6926873926
       11    847  1536011164
       11    120  7680946026
       11    636  2152889253
       11    940  6045178903
       11   4066 12011221732
       11  34475  6427632883
       11   6576  4537007282
       11    421  3222973463
       11    477  4294366585
       11    437   640149590
       11     21     4865750
       11   1483  2022528739
       11    694  2243225874
       11    469  7185784295
       11   2844  2622604529
       11    217  2634144335
       11    289   835888890
       11    767  2186788589
       11    292  1455599850
       11    115   870804648
       11    276  1216684768
       11  38667  6090175841
       11     52  8626680352
       11  18360  1486048781
       11    553  4266666334
       11    377  3404593358
       11     74   162800046
       11    349  1980814888
       11    838  2134759918
       11     13    61335596
       11    315   787569849
       11   1713  1358541557
       11   5172  3627373556
       11   1633  1720414518
       11    981  3257169818
       11   4045 10465398231
       11    378  2947649588
       11    687  2762932637
       11    441  1789621893
       11    258  1649460903
       11    602  6536876931
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Why do you want to use clustering "to prove is there's non linear relationship between Uploads and Subscribes"? Sounds to me that comparing the fit of a linear model and non-linear model would just as well prove your point.

Comment: @Annet, I already used other ways like ```summary(model)```, ```diagnostic plots```, ```corrplot```, ```ggpairs```, etc. The clustering is the final one I want to use.

Comment: I believe clustering does not explain whether there is a relationship or not, be it linear or nonlinear in nature ... ?

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 indeed, clustering explains whether some observations are closer to each other/more similar than observations in other groups.  It doesn't say anything about the relationship. But seeing the number of "things" already done, it feels a bit like "I just do a lot of stuff that might sound good" .

Comment: Clustering is very sensitive to the scales of the variables. Here, you are clustering Subscribe (maximum value 103 and Uploads (maximum value 154714) so you are really just clustering Uploads. The simple Pearson correlation is .079 with a p-value of .08 so there is no significant linear correlation. Taking a log transform on each variable, there is also no significant non-linear correlation.